# Generate ID's above a certain value

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, auto-increment

In my JPA+Hibernate+MySQL app I have an entity like so:

```
@Entity
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    // columns....
}
```

This works perfectly fine, but the generated id values are, as expected, 1, 2, 3, etc. However, users are going to see this ID, and the client wants the id's to be longer (because he finds it looks nicer), from the day of the application release.

How can I change the ID generation of Hibernate or MySQL (I don't know who actually does it now) so that ID's are always higher than a certain value, e.g. 100000000?

Comment: Wouldn't that [just](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) be to `ALTER TABLE Room AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000000;` where `Room` is the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways. For example you can create a custom hibernate generator. But the easiest way is to simply tell MySQL where to start counting from:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

Answer (score 1):

generated value without a strategy defaults to "AUTO" and that means the database is providing the id value.  You need to seed the column in MYSQL to provide the correct value

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000;
```

That should work. Although being a purely cosmetic change you should just change it on output (And input) so that the data isn't corrupted by [PHB-syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointy-haired_Boss)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not purely cosmetic, because users could send that ID to us and we'd need it to find logs, etc.